# Ssh connection from python and read file from php?

Tags: php, python

I want to connect remote server using python fetch data from php from that same server.

Comment: SO is not a place to keep personal notes

Comment: Thanks and its not a place to argue but solve question answers.

Comment: @user6795317, SO is not a code-service website. Kindly show us what you've done and we'll be glad to assist you.

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
import os
import paramiko
import time
import datetime
import json

#Define Server Detail for sftp

hostname = "hostname"
username = "username"
password  = "password"
serverpath = "/var/www/projectfolder"

server, user, password, port = (hostname, username, password, 2020)
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
paramiko.util.log_to_file('paramiko.log')
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.load_host_keys(os.path.expanduser(os.path.join("~", ".ssh", "known_hosts")))
ssh.connect(server, username=user, password=password, port=port)
ssh_stdin, ssh_stdout, ssh_stderr = ssh.exec_command('ls /tmp')

error = ssh_stderr.read()

# print "err", (error), len(error)

sftp = ssh.open_sftp()

# data = sftp.listdir()

data = sftp.listdir(serverpath)

dir_paths = []

# for i in data:
#     dir_paths.append(i)
#     print (i)

for line in data:
    if line.endswith('.mp4'):
        print(line)

#The local path where files to be downloded
#local_path = "/root/backup/"

#The Remote path of the Server
#sftp.chdir(remote_path)
#remote_path = '/root/backup/'

#print "changed"

# for filename in (sftp.listdir()):
#
#   fullpath = os.path.join(remote_path, filename)
# # get timestamp of file in epoch secon
#   timestamp  = sftp.stat(fullpath).st_atime
#   createtime = datetime.datetime.now()
#   now = time.mktime(createtime.timetuple())
#   datetime.timedelta = now - timestamp
#
# #Download the latest file
#   if datetime.timedelta < 86400:
#       print filename
#
#       localpath = os.path.join(local_path, filename)
#       print "downloading %s" % filename
#       sftp.get(filename, localpath)
#       print "downloading %s completed" % filename

sftp.close()
ssh.close()


So this is my code and i want to execute it from php script.
```